# Is there a way to concatenate CSS class selectors?

Tags: html, css, sass

This may not be the right wording, which may also be the reason I could not find any answers previously, so my apologies if this is a duplicate.

I am writing a basic CSS framework/guideline that will be used for multiple projects, and I wanted to create a number of classes that will have styles associated with them off the bat in order to make development quicker.

For example, I am looking to be able to do something along the lines of the following:

`<div class="flex-column-wrap"></div>`

Where I would write an SCSS selector which would accomplish something along the lines of:

```
.flex {
  display:flex;
  &.-column {
    flex-direction:column;
  }
  &.-wrap {
    flex-wrap:wrap;
  }
  &.-column-wrap {
    flex-direction:column;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
  }
}
```

I know the `&` selector would not work in this situation, because it is one class, which is what I was trying to accomplish to **not** add 3 individual classes, like so `<div class="flex column wrap"></div>`

Not sure if something like this is possible or if it would just make more sense to write out all of the classes individually. I appreciate any insight into this!

Comment: Not really clear what you are trying to achieve :/ Maybe try to put some examples?

Comment: Why not using Bootstrap 4 (flex based) and add your color theme to it.

Comment: There are a lot more reasons than just flex based I wanted to use, that was just one example of where I would want to utilize multiple class names that apply different styles, that Bootstrap does not have built in @bron

Comment: Yep, I'm aware of that. Bootstrap is meant to add your own custom classes to prevent that each site is a BS looking site :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `.` after each `&` to get the classes that you want: `flex`, `flex-column`, `flex-wrap`, and `flex-column-wrap`.

```
.flex {
  display:flex;
  &-column {
    flex-direction:column;
  }
  &-wrap {
    flex-wrap:wrap;
  }
  &-column-wrap {
    flex-direction:column;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
  }
}
```

`&` allows you to take the parent selector and append the following text to it, so `&-column` in your code will create a CSS rule for `.flex-column`.

Comment: Awesome thank you very much! I didn't realize you could append it like that with the `&-`!